# React application hosted in S3 bucket with OKTA OIDC Authorization grant with PKCE flow (AuthSdk error)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, openid-connect, okta

Can you please let me know if we can successfully deploy a React application hosted in S3 bucket that is also integrated with a OIDC authentication provider (OKTA) and specifically Authorization grant with PKCE flow. I am facing the issue (*AuthSdk Error*: pkCE requires a modern browser with encryption sup…PS protocol. PKCE requires secure HTTPS protocol cloudfront)

We tried to follow AWS documentation and able to host the React SPA as a static website and had also tried different hacks to be able to successfully redirect the callback to the react router (by adding #! in the redirect rules) and eventually could login into the application using OKTA login, but the callback will not succeed due to the above error.

Is it correct to use the S3 bucket url as origin instead of S3 Website endpoint (custom origin) for Cloudfront distribution and will it be helpful to get around the pkce error with https url, because the S3 bucket url seems to be served through https, but S3 website endpoint will only be served through http.

Will cloudfront use https url when S3 bucket is configured as origin or will it be using http url because the S3 bucket is published as static website.

Can you please share any thoughts on this approach. Thank you!

Regards,
Sudharshan.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Okta as a federated identity provider in cognito and React as a SPA for the frontend app. It'll work as long as you create a Cloudfront distribution pointing to the S3 bucket where you uploaded the react bundle of your app.

You need https for Okta to be able to redirect you to your required callback URLs but S3 only provides you with http. So you need to deploy it to Cloudfront to enable https.

Just keep in mind to point the `Origin Domain Name` in Cloudfront to the url that S3 generated after enabling static hosting.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you Hemant for the reply. Yes, I have used the S3 website url as origin in Cloudfront. Also, I have configured both Cloudfront url and also S3 website as the callback url in OKTA application setup. 
However, after OKTA login is completed and returns back to the application on Callback url, cloudfront no longer serves the application, but redirects to S3 bucket url and throws the above error.

Comment: The callback URL that you'll provide to okta will only be for cloudfront not s3. You'll only interface with Cloudfront url now. S3 now just serves as storage.

Comment: Ok Hemant. Will check on that. 
Just to clarify, did you setup OKTA application as implicit grant flow or authorization grant flow with PKCE?
If you are using Cognito as idp (which in turn federates OKTA), are you generating the authorization url for Cognito explicitly or using any SDK to achieve that?

Comment: @SudharshanReddy I see that you made it work. I was actually using SAML instead of OAuth with implicit grant and cognito has a predefined naming for the auth URL where you input the id provider, client and some other stuff ...so yes explicitly.

Comment: Ok Hemant. I finally ended up with below settings:
1) Not host the S3 bucket as static website hosting 
2) No public access to S3, but only to Cloudfront
3) Change the callback url to something like https://hostname/callback instead of https://hostname/implicit/callback. This helped the callback to redirect to index.html in root folder not to https://hostname/implicit folder and avoid searching other *.js files from implicit folder and configure Cloudfront with 404 redirect as well.
4) Not sure why it is not mentioned in many places to server SPA application without hosting as S3 Website.

Answer (score 1):

The standard technique is to:

- Use S3 as a place to upload your web static content
- Use CloudFront to host over HTTPS URLs
- Also use CloudFront as a Content Delivery Network for improved web performance

Have a look at the below blog posts of mine, which also host a React SPA:

- [SPA AWS Deployment](https://authguidance.com/2018/12/02/spa-content-deployment/)
- [AWS DNS Domain + SSL Certificate Setup](https://authguidance.com/2018/12/02/cloud-domain-setup/)

Out of interest you can run the deployed SPA from the above blog posts using the URL and test login account on my [quick start page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to resolve the issue after making the below changes. Just posting sooner to avoid forgetting the steps that helped resolving my issue. Please correct if something is supposed to be done in more appropriate way.

1. Removed the S3 bucket website url from the OKTA setup as Hemant suggested above
2. Updated the S3 404 redirection rule to have the cloudfront address as given below (along with 403 redirect rule)

```html
 <RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>xyz.cloudfront.net</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#!/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Earlier, I used the S3 website url for HostName instead, that redirected back into S3 bucket (http) and seems to be one of reason for react application failed with pkce error.

3. Updated the Cloudfront behavior to forward the query strings (this is one step that I missed earlier which is required to retain the callback authorization code to pass to the react codebase.)
   [image]
4. Also, updated the Error document to index.html in S3 bucket website configuration.
5. Properly replaced the #!/ from the hash url in history object and used pushState.

```js
var hash = window.location.hash;
const newHashpath = hash.replace("#!/",""); //(/#!(\/.*)$/.exec(window.location.pathname) || [])[1];
if (newHashpath) {
   // history.replace(path);
   window.history.pushState({},'',newHashpath);
}
```